# How to apply CSS color on parent element using a color picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a color picker which appears by clicking on pencil glyphicon. I just want to apply color from color picker on list elements i.e. which is grand parent of pencil glyphicon. I have a following ruby front end code:

```
 <% categories.each(function (category) { %>
    <li id="<%= category.id %>" class="Round-boxes my-sortable">

      <% if(category.get("is_owner")) { %>   
        <div class="color-picker-pencil picker">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </div>
      <% } %> 
    </li>
  <% }); %>
```

I am following this [tutorail](http://colpick.com/plugin) according to which I have a following JS code with a slighter change.

JS code:

```js
 applyColor: function(event) {
 
   myel = $(event.target).parent().parent()
   console.log(myel);
   $('.picker').colpick({
     layout: 'hex',
     submit: 0,
     colorScheme: 'dark',
     onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb, myel, bySetColor) {

       $(myel).css('background-color:', '#' + hex);
     }
   }).keyup(function() {

     $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);

   });

 }
```

What Should i do to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a syntax error in `applyColor` function and a little code change, I replaced following code in place of existing:

```
    applyColor: function(event){
    $('.picker').colpick({
      layout:'hex',
      submit:0,
      colorScheme:'dark',
      onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,myel,bySetColor) {

        myel = $(myel).parent();
        $(myel).css('background-color','#'+hex);

      }

    }).keyup(function(){

    $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);

    });

  }
```

And every thing works fine.
See the line two lines of code inside `onChange` body. And compare it with  code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the parent() Jquery function?

```
onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb, myel, bySetColor) {

       $(myel).parent('li').css('background-color:', '#' + hex);
     }
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but may be it works. Thanks for your answer :)